# A more efficient means than for loop in python in case i+1 element has correlation with ith element

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I'm having an issue about computing efficiency. Specifically, I have an *np.array*, `pos[]`, and the inner elements are following as i+1-th element equals to the result of an operation (Metropolis Algorithm) implemented on i-th element with some initial value in 0th.

I wrote a for loop to manupulate such operation, like

```py
for n in range(N):
          pos1[n+1]=Metropolis_He(pos1[n])
```

The problem is while I do the following calculations later, I found it is so time consuming. I know np.array can dealing with parallel operations for array element. However, in this case since there is correlation between neighbour elements ( I have to finish the operation at i-th element, so then I determine the value of i+1-th), do you have any more efficient means than `for` loop?

Comment: Without changing the function `Metropolis_He` which is a black-box here, there is no way to vectorize the code. In fact, there is a *dependency-chain* preventing any possible vectorization. In general, in such a case, the key is to try to break the long dependency chain, but this is not always possible. Otherwise, the solution left is to optimize `Metropolis_He`. I might be a bit faster to use lists in this case. Numba/Cython might also help if `Metropolis_He` can be compiled.

Comment: Thanks @JérômeRichard, could you go more about the *dependency-chain* and the possible alteration of `Metropolis_He`?

Comment: Regarding the dependency chain, an example is a simple loop : if you do `for v in arr: s += v` (with `arr` a floating point array), then each iteration is dependent of the previous one and this is an issue because the operation cannot be executed in parallel (SIMD, multiple threads, ILP, etc.). In this simple case, you can actually use a pair-wise summation (which is what Numpy use under the hood) which is not strictly equivalent to the initial loop but very close. Since `Metropolis_He` is a black-box function, IDK if such transformation is possible. Probably not, but who know...

Comment: Note that setting an array items is slow because every call to Numpy typically takes about few microseconds (at least 0.5 on most machines even for basic operations). This is because of the way the CPython [interpreter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing)) works (and many checks, function calls, etc in Numpy). The key is to minimize the function calls to Numpy. Numba can help to remove part of the overheads but this is very dependent for what the black-box function does. I cannot say much more without the code of `Metropolis_He`.